# Autodesk viewer. Some fonts are not applied to the drawing (DWG)

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk, autodesk-model-derivative

Some fonts are not applied to the drawing, the customer has provided fonts with which the drawing works correctly on the web version. After adding these fonts to the references an error occurs and the fonts are not applied to the drawing.(https://i.stack.imgur.com/hRHRL.png)

As before with other drawings we added these fonts to the references and everything worked correctly, but now for some reason some of the fonts are not applied.[references and font path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S9bMH.png)

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You will need to identify the font files referenced by the DWG.

You might need to open the DWG in AutoCAD to inspect the entities and/or text styles to identify the font names or font file names.

Adding the missing fonts to the translation job will improve the 2D outputs' visual fidelity but not the 3D outputs, as the DWG conversion currently removes TEXT and MTEXT entities from model space before generating the output for Viewer.